# Tax_query terms ID's using variable

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I want to make a custom WP_Query using custom taxonomy terms ID´s.

Example of the term’s ID’s :  19,18,214,226,20

Why does this work:

```
$query_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'works’,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'materials',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array( 19,18,214,226,20 ),
        )
    ),
);
```

It shows all items from all taxonomy terms ID’s,

But this doesn’t:

`$tax = '19,18,214,226,20';`

```
$query_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'works',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'materials',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array( $tax ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Using the variable `$tax` the query result only shows items the first term ID (19), and ignores all the others.

Why does this happens and how can i use the variable in the tax_query instead of hardcode the ID’s ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you are making an array with a single string inside.

Check if making $tax into an array before passing it will work:

```
$tax = array( 19, 18, 214, 226, 20 );

$query_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'works',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'materials',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => $tax,
        )
    ),
);
```

If you need to make an array from a formatted string, you can use the `explode` PHP function that takes a delimiter and a string, and returns an array, like so:

```
$tax_string = '19,18,214,226,20';
$tax_array = explode( ',', $tax_string );
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Because in php, `$tax = '19,18,214,226,20';` is a string. and you can't  wrap a string within `array()` and  create an array  :)

You may need  something like :

```
function comma_separated_to_array($string, $separator = ',')
{
  //Explode on comma
  $vals = explode($separator, $string);

  //Trim whitespace
  foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
    $vals[$key] = trim($val);
  }
  //Return empty array if no items found
  //http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#114273
  return array_diff($vals, array(""));
}
```

and use  it as

```
$terms= comma_separated_to_array($tax);
```

Comment: Great function for separating comma separated values into an array but overkill for the above question.

Comment: Thanks. 4 lines of code of less than 30 characters each it not an overkill, I think :)

Comment: Or just use `$ids = explode(',', $tax);`